# R creating a binary matrix from information in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix indicating in which column there should be a value 1. All other columns should have a value of 0. For example,

```
m = matrix(c(3,3,3,5,12,13),nrow = 3)
```

How should I efficitietly create the following matrix?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[,1]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
[,2]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0
[,3]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a matrix of 0's with desired dimensions

```
out <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 14)
```

Then `cbind` a vector of row indices with `c(m)`, i.e. column positions

```
tmp <- cbind(seq_len(3), c(m))
```

`tmp` is a matrix that you can use now to replace desired positions with 1

```
out[tmp] <- 1
out
#         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#    [1,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#    [2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0
#    [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0
```

---

Another, probably less efficient way, could be this

```
t(apply(m, 1, tabulate, nbins = 14))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a matrix of row ids and elements from your original matrix `m1`
Create a matrix poplulated with zeros with the same number of rows as the original and number of columns one more than the maximium element in the original.

```r
m1 <- matrix(c(rep(1:nrow(m), ncol(m)), as.vector(m)), ncol = 2)

mx <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = max(m) + 1)
mx[m1] <- 1
mx
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#> [1,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0
#> [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>